# Excel macro - sending automatic email when transferring data from one sheet to another (copy full row)

Tags: excel, vba, email, excel-2016

I'm working on the Macro below which transfers the selected rows to a new sheet and deletes it from the original sheet when pressing a command button.

I'm trying to get it to send an automatic email when running this macro to inform xDepartment that yDepartment has transferred work. I want the body of the email to contain the active rows in their entirety which are being transferred.

At the moment, when tranferring the rows, I can click on any cell in the row in the yDepartment worksheet (adjacent and non-adjacent) and it will transfer columns A:L to the xDepartment worksheet. But when I add the macro to also send an email, it will only send the details of the specific cells that I have selected, instead of the full row.

Also, if the cells are non-adjacent (e.g. I'm transferring rows 4-5 and 8-10 at the same time), it sends the entire sheet, which I don't want.

Does anyone know how I can fix this so that when work is transferred, the automatic email contains the same content as that which is transferred?

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Pass_to_xDepartment()

If MsgBox("Do you want to pass the selected tours to XDepartment?", vbYesNo, "Pass to XDepartment") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

For Each WSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
            If WSheet.FilterMode Then
                WSheet.ShowAllData
            End If
        End If
        For Each DTable In WSheet.ListObjects
            If DTable.ShowAutoFilter Then
                DTable.Range.AutoFilter
                DTable.Range.AutoFilter
            End If
        Next DTable
    Next WSheet

   Dim Sendrng As Range

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Note: if the selection is one cell it will send the whole worksheet
    Set Sendrng = Selection

    'Create the mail and send it
    With Sendrng

        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            .Introduction = "The following rows have been completed. "

            With .Item
                .To = "EMAIL"
                .CC = 
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Updated"
                .Send
            End With

        End With
    End With

StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

'Declare variables
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

'Set variables
    Set sht1 = Sheets("YDepartment")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("XDepartment")

'Select Entire Row.Resize(ColumnSize:=12)
    Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Selection.Parent.Range("A:L")).Select

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
    lastRow = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Selection
        .Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
        .EntireRow.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send the details of the whole row, you can set the `Sendrng` variable by choosing its contents via range rather than assigning it to `selection`.

Note: the code was slightly rearranged to send the email after transferring the data for this to work.

This should also compensate for selecting different ranges and wanting the avoid sending the entire sheet.

```
Sub Pass_to_xDepartment()

    'Declare variables
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastRow2 As Long
    Dim WSheet As Variant
    Dim DTable As Variant
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim sht3 As Worksheet

    If MsgBox("Do you want to pass the selected tours to XDepartment?", vbYesNo, "Pass to XDepartment") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    For Each WSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
            If WSheet.FilterMode Then
                WSheet.ShowAllData
            End If
        End If
        For Each DTable In WSheet.ListObjects
            If DTable.ShowAutoFilter Then
                DTable.Range.AutoFilter
                DTable.Range.AutoFilter
            End If
        Next DTable
    Next WSheet

    'Set variables
    Set sht1 = Sheets("YDepartment")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("XDepartment")

    'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
    lastRow = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Select Entire Row.Resize(ColumnSize:=12)
    Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Selection.Parent.Range("A:L")).Select

    With Selection
        .Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
        lastRow2 = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    Set sht3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    sht3.Name = "temp"
    'Note: if the selection is one cell it will send the whole worksheet
    Set Sendrng = sht2.Range("A" & (lastRow + 1) & ":L" & lastRow2)
    Sendrng.Copy Destination:=sht3.Range("A1")

 On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Create the mail and send it
    sht3.Activate
    lastRow2 = sht3.Range("A" & sht3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Sendrng = sht3.Range("A1:L" & lastRow2)

    With Sendrng

        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            .Introduction = "The following rows have been completed. "

            With .Item
                .To = "EMAIL"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Updated"
                .Send
            End With

        End With
    End With

StopMacro:

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```

Also, its good practice to declare or `Dim` all your variables at the top of your programs but not necessary

Best of luck

Comment: Hi @Kubie, thank you for your help - we are now getting emails with entire rows, which is amazing. There a few bugs still though? We can't select non-adjacent rows and pass them over as it sends the entire sheet again. Also, I think there's an issue where the email is sending after it's copied over the details to the other sheet, but it's copying the cells that have replaced the transferred data on the original sheet. Is is it possible for me to make the email send first and then transfer the data? Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: @LizH hey so I editted my response above and fixed most of the problems you mentioned. You can now send 2 non-adjacent selections and also send from the correct sheet. I could also change it so that it transfers the data after the email but right now this approach was the easiest lol

Comment: Hi @Kubie - I'm so sorry! I took a few days off work last week, and only just came back to the office. Yes, the new suggestions send the row being transferred, and it sends non-adjacent rows as well. Thank you so much for all your help!